# external table in Hive not showing data

Tags: hive

I created a table in Hive

```
create external table if not exists firsttest 
(id int, 
name char(50), 
exp char(50))

row format delimited FIELDS TERMINATED BY '/t'

stored as textfile
location '/user/amit/test1'
```

The file on test1 location is a simple .txt file with 3 rows tab delimited as below

```
1   kiran    oracle

2   das      oracle

3   rahul    python
```

the external table get created. However when I do select * from firsttest
then I see 3 rows will all NULL data. 
Can anyone explain why? why I see all null values and no data.

Thanks.
Aks

Answer (score 2):

Fields terminated by delimiter has to be **`\t`** instead of **`/t`**.

Drop the existing table and recreate table with correct delimiter and then try to select the data from the table.

***Example:***

```
drop table firsttest;
create external table if not exists firsttest 
(id int, 
name char(50), 
exp char(50))
row format delimited FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
stored as textfile;
```

Comment: @aks,Great..Could you accept the answer to close this thread as resolved! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work